# How to add options and customs to a jQuery application

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a jQuery application, which I want to provide some options to it so the user will changes some values based on their prefrecens. So I have seen many plugins have some sort of options in the head tag that user can modify and they will be affected directly in the plugin. Something like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $.MyApp({
    background : #000,
    foreground : red,
    blur : 10px
  });
});
```

So let's say I have a js file already that works fine, but I want to give accessibility to the user of my code to modify some default values. 
How can I do this? 
I have made a sample application that blurs the background image. [JSFiddle](https://goo.gl/xE1xS9)

Can you provide some example based on my demo to see how such a structure can work and overwrite the default values? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example this is how you can provide default, but overridable option in a jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.MyApp=function(options){
    var defaults={
        background : "#000",
        foreground : "#fff",
        blur : "5px"
    };
    var options=$.extend(defaults,options);

    $(this).css("-webkit-filter", "blur(" + options.blur + ")");  
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is what I am looking for but I do not know how to use it. I made a demo and updated my question. can you answer based on the demo please? Thanks

Comment: @TheGuy here is  [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/fa1dyjhk/1/) showing how you can use it

Comment: Gavriel, +1 but you dont really need the "selector" parameter do you? I expect you'd use this like `$(selector).MyApp({someOption:'value'});` right?

Comment: Also should update `$(".imageBox").css` to `this.css` And it couldnt hurt to show how to call it :)